# Delphi Firemonkey - loading style at runtime

Tags: delphi, styles, runtime, firemonkey

I have loaded a couple of the sample styles from ......\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles as resources into my project and am 'simply' trying to load one of them at runtime.

I'm using the following code to try and do this:

```
var
  vResourceStream : TResourceStream;
begin

  vResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create( HInstance, 'DARKSTYLE', RT_RCDATA );

  try
    StyleBook1.LoadFromStream( vResourceStream );
  finally
    vResourceStream.Free;
  end;
```

It compiles ok but when I run it I get a bunch of errors, the first being 'Property Align does not exist' then 'Error reading TStyleBook.Align: Property Align does not exist' and it seems to do this for a bunch more atributes, Height etc.

Can someone give me some pointers as to how to solve it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not that I know a bit about FMX, but AFAIU the .style files are *resource* definition files. Instead of reading the stylebook object from the stream, you should read its resource:

```
StyleBook1.Resource.LoadFromStream( vResourceStream );
```

Comment: Ignore me. For some reason when the user clicks on the TListBox the procedure fires twice. So, your answer was spot on. Thank you very much indeed. I've just got to work out the odd listbox behaviour now :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, there are [LoadFromStream](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Controls.TStyleBook.LoadFromStream) and [LoadFromFile](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Controls.TStyleBook.LoadFromFile) methods at TStyleBook, but there is also TStyleStreaming class with an extra [LoadFromResource](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Styles.TStyleStreaming.LoadFromResource) utility method (apart from its own LoadFromStream and LoadFromFile). Probably they should add a LoadFromStream to TStyleBook class too (guess it would call into the respective TStyleStreaming one)

Comment: btw, instead of using an RCDATA resource one could opt to use a DataModule with multiple StyleBooks in it and reference a specific StyleBook from the respective property of the form(s) they want (after they "use" the DataModule's unit in those forms' units), or tell the StyleBook they want from that DataModule to use the StyleManager (set property UseStyleManager to true, after they set it to false to the old one). Note you can override the StyleBook explicitly at any form(s)